# Git pull overwritten all changes

Tags: git

I have created new folders and added new files in my local repository and also modified codes.

But after my teammate pushed her codes, and I want to synchronise using git pull after committed.

I have used add all files that enables git to track any files.
but everytime I used git pull, my work is totally overwritten by my teammate's work.
Also the files I created are removed. My codes are overwritten.

The IDE I used is Xcode.
I just simply used "git commit -a -m 'xxx'" and "git pull", but it worked before.

How to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify if you have used an IDE (what IDE) or what commands you have used (the output from `git reflog -10` may also be usefull)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be overwritten, but merged instead. If you have conflicts within some files you should resolve them manually by editing files in some graphical git program or manually (highly NOT recommended) and commit the merge after with "git commit" with no message specified then "git push" it to the remote side...

Comment: I found it is the auto merge in someway, but my files are deleted shown as deleted mode in command line. Is there someway to get rid of some auto-merge?

Comment: Then it means the files are deleted by you or other third-party software, just check for "mergetool" option in "~/.gitconfig" global config file, maybe you have something there. Anyway, you can always rollback your files by doing "git checkout ." to go back to the current revision